# Rails session inside js erb empty

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session

I want to use `session[:path]` inside js template,but it is empty

i have defined `session[:path]='my path'`
and then want to put into js like

```
  window.location.href='<%= session[:path]%>';
```

but return `<%= p session[:path] => nil%>`

controller

```
    class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :js
  layout false
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate(auth_options)

    if resource && resource.active_for_authentication?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    end
  end




  def path
    user = User.find_by(email:params[:email])
    conversation = Conversation.find_by(product_id:params[:product_id],recipient_id:params[:product_owner_id])
      # binding.pry
    p params


    if conversation
      session[:path] = conversation_url(conversation.id)
      p 'conv'
    elsif params[:product_owner_id].to_i == user.id
      session[:path] = request.referer
      p 'back'
    else
      conversation = Conversation.create(sender_id:user.id, recipient_id:params[:product_owner_id],product_id:params[:product_id])
      session[:path] = conversation_url(conversation.id)
      p 'new'
    end

    render json: :ok
  end

end
```

javascript template /sessions/create.js.erb

```
 <% if user_signed_in?%>
  window.location='<%= session[:path] %>';
<% else %>
  $('#login_popup input').parent().addClass('inputbox_error');
  $('#log_error_messages').show();
  $('input').keydown(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('inputbox_error')
    $('#log_error_messages').hide();
  })
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please include the (controller?) code where you set `session[:path]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `session[:path]` inside your `path.js.erb` file.

If you want to use some ruby variables inside your js files (like application.js) I would recommend [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon)

Comment: so i cant use `session[:path]` inside my `create js.erb`?

Comment: You defined session[:path] inside `path` action, not inside `create`

Comment: no, it's a request session. See here: http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/Session

Comment: is it possible to create global session for app?

Comment: It's a not rule of thumb. I'd recommend using `before_action` for tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using `session[:path]` inside `app/views/sessions/path.js.erb` (not within a file in `app/assets/javascript`)? If so you are on the right track.

You say that `<%= p session[:path] %>` "returns" nothing. That is right, because the return value of `p` is `nil`. It prints what you give it, but it doesn't return anything.

I suspect your file actually is rendering the right Javascript, but nothing is happening because you should say `window.location = ...` not `window.location.href = ...`.

Edit: By the way, usually people store things in `session` only if they are going to need it again in a later request. If you are just trying to pass a variable to your JS view, you know that you could use an instance variable, right? Like this: `@redirect_path = conversation_url(conversation.id)`.

Comment: i do not have `path` template its method for collect data from ajax request only. i  just definded `session` there and try to use it inside `create` action

Comment: Ah now that I see `create.js.erb` I understand the flow a bit more. Can you clarify what is happening that you don't expect? Also, this looks like an XSS vulnerability: `window.location='<%= session[:path] %>'` in the case of `session[:path] = request.referer` since you aren't escaping it.